# Boost program will not working on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker, boost-asio

I have this program which uses Boost::Asio for sockets. I pretty much altered some code from the Boost examples. The program compiles and runs just like it should on Windows in VS. However, when I compile the program on Linux and run it, I get a Segmentation fault.

I posted the code [here](http://pastebin.com/jvLhkfrX)

The command I use to compile it is this:

```
c++ -I/appl/htopopt/Linux_x86_64/NTL-5.4.2/include 
-I/appl/htopopt/Linux_x86_64/boost_1_43_0/include 
mpqs.cpp mpqs_polynomial.cpp mpqs_host.cpp -o mpqs_host 
-L/appl/htopopt/Linux_x86_64/NTL-5.4.2/lib -lntl 
-L/appl/htopopt/Linux_x86_64/gmp-4.2.1/lib -lgmp -lm 
-L/appl/htopopt/Linux_x86_64/boost_1_43_0/lib -lboost_system 
-lboost_thread -static -lpthread
```

By commenting out code, I have found out that I get the Segmentation fault due to the following line:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
```

Can anyone provide any assistance, as to what may be the problem (and the solution)?

Thanks!

Edit: I tried changing the program to a minimal example, using no other libraries or headers, just boost/asio.hpp:

```
#define DEBUG 0

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {  
     boost::asio::io_service io_service;
     return 0;
}
```

I also removed other library inclusions and linking on compilation, however this minimal example still gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: I doubt this is the answer, but I've had big problems that look just like yours with using boost and the gold linker on linux.  Switching back to the older ld linker fixed all my problems for me.

Comment: Which compiler and Linux OS are you using? If your minimal example still segfaults, I'd start looking at your environment.

Answer (score 4):

From the GCC online documentation of the `-static` option:

> On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking with the shared libraries.

Boost can support static-only linkage but only if it was configured that way when the OS Package maintainer built it. Are you absolutely certain you should be using this flag? If not, try recompiling without the flag and see if that doesn't take care of the problem.

Comment: This may be the problem, without `-static` your test program compiles and runs fine on my fedora12 box.  If I remember right, you may not be able to statically compile anything that requires pthreads.